# How can I turn an fir1 stop-band filter into a multiple stop-band filter

Tags: matlab

A single band-stop filter can be made by fir1(N,[w1 w2],'stop'), where N is the number of filter coefficients, w1 is the beginning stop frequency, w2 the ending stop frequency, how can I turn this into a multiple stop-band filter? Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Comment: If you're trying to block, say, 2 sets of frequencies [w1:w2] and [w3:w4], why not just build 2 separate bandstop filters?

Comment: Another option is to use an inverted filter band. In pseudocode-- 1.) Do `x_filt=lowpass(x_orig,w<w2)` followed by 2.) Do `x_filt=highpass(x_filt,w>w1)`, followed by 3.) `x_new=x_orig-x_filt`

Answer (score 4):

use conv to determine the proper coefficients:

```
b =  fir1(50,[0.2 0.3],'stop');
b2 =  fir1(50,[0.7 0.8],'stop');
freqz(conv(b,b2),1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 'DC-0' instead of 'stop'and give it the start and end of each band:

```
bd1start=1500/(fs/2);
bd1end=3500/(fs/2);

bd2start=6500/(fs/2);
bd2end=8500/(fs/2);
order=64;
bb=fir1( order, [bd1start bd1end bd2start bd2end ],'DC-1' );
```