# How to combine filter coefficients for multiple stop band filters - Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I would like to combine several stop band filters into a single filter to understand how the filter changes phase when there are mutiple bands removed.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474043/how-can-i-turn-an-fir1-stop-band-filter-into-a-multiple-stop-band-filter) provides a solution for two filters, but what if there were more than two filter bands?

Here is an image showing the gains and phase of each separate filter.

So my questions are:

1. What happens to the phase if I filter the data in five separate operations
2. Can I combine the filtering steps into a single step?

I am using the butter and freqz functions in Matlab.

```
[b,a] = butter(order,cutoff/(fs/2),'high');
[h,w] = freqz(b,a,fs);
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Note that you might be able to see the results more clearly if you [`unwrap` the phase](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) before plotting it; the discontinuity in the phase is not really there: it is just a result of the fact that the phase returned from `freqz` is always in the range `[-pi, pi]`. You might also want to plot the response in `dB re 1` by plotting `20 * log10(abs(h))`.

Answer (score 3):

The phases and magntudes (dB) will sum. If you want to see on Matlab you need to [cascate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dfilt.cascade.html) the filter, for exemple:

```
% computes the coefficients
[b1,a1]=butter(8,0.6);          
[b2,a2]=butter(8,0.4,'high');   
[b3,a3]=butter(8,0.2,'high');   
% creates the filters
H1=dfilt.df2t(b1,a1);
H2=dfilt.df2t(b2,a2);
H3=dfilt.df2t(b3,a3);
% creates the cascate filter
Hcas=dfilt.cascade(H1,H2,H3)   
% plot    
Hcas.freqz()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. During convolution phase effects accumulate and the total phase effect is the sum of phase effects of all filters
2. Yes, you just need to convolve all of them to obtain the new filter: conv(conv(filter1,filter2),filter3)

Comment: Interesting. If I convolve the filter coefficients and then phase plot should show steps down from 0 to -2pi then -2pi to -4pi, etc at each stopband? I'll try it.

Comment: No, if you sum the  filter phase responses graphically, you can observe 5 phase shots in single phase plot